# Speech Recognition to enter values in datagridview C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview, speech-recognition

I need to enter marks in a datagrid by converting speech to text. Is there any methods. I have no idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dont know what exactly you want to do, but speech recognition is relatively easy in C#, check for example this out: http://csharp-tricks-en.blogspot.de/2011/03/speech-recognition-part-1-dictation-mode.html